# Cardinality natural numbers

Tags: cardinals, natural-numbers

Is the cardinality of the natural numbers a natural number?

$|\mathbb{N}| \in \mathbb{N}\text{ or } |\mathbb{N}| \notin \mathbb{N}$, that is the question.

Comment: Each natural number is a specific positive integer, so no. Even interpreting $n$ as a set with $n$ elements, it is not equipotent to $N$, an infinite set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$|\mathbb{N}| \notin \mathbb{N}$

$\mathbb{N}$ doesn't contain any kind of $\infty$.
Yes, $\mathbb{N}$ contains huge numbers, but not infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that what "$\mathbb{N}$" and the "cardinality" is.

If you look at them with their definitions, the answer will be very easy.

In the set theory, natural numbers are defined like this:

$0 := \emptyset$

$1 := {0 \cup \left\{ 0 \right\}}$,

$2 := {1 \cup \left\{ 1 \right\}}$

$\dots$

and finally, the whole set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest "set" $X$ with the property "$\emptyset\in X$ and if $x\in X$ then $x\cup\left\{x\right\}\in X$" (we are assuming the existence of such sets in $\mathbf{ZFC}$). Notice that there is no largest element of $\mathbb{N}$ since every member of $\mathbb{N}$ has a successor in $\mathbb{N}$.

More generally, a set $\alpha$ is an ordinal number if $\alpha$ is strictly-well-ordered by the binary relation "$\in$". [Ordinal Number (Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) can read for more detailed information, especially for ordinal arithmetic.

For example, $\mathbb{N}+1:=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is also an ordinal.

Now, cardinality of a set $X$ is the smallest ordinal bijective to $X$, and an ordinal is also a cardinal if its cardinality is equal to itself. For example $\mathbb{N}$ is also a cardinal, and it is the smallest infinite cardinal. $\mathbb{N} + 1$ is not a cardinal. [Cardinal Number (wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) can read for more detailed information.

If we look natural numbers as a set, we write $\mathbb{N}$. If we look them as an ordinal, we write $\omega$, and for cardinal, we write $\aleph_0$.

Then the answer is very easy, since no ordinal is an element of itself.